# in case + verb form

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis, modal-verbs

Thinking things through, here ...

> (a) *Bring a pen, in case you need to take some notes*
>
> (b) *Bring a pen, in case you needed to take some notes*
>
> (c) *Bring a pen, in case you might need to take some notes*

and here

> (d) *Take your umbrella, in case it rains*
>
> (e) *Take your umbrella, in case it rained*
>
> (f) *Take your umbrella, in case it might rain*

Without thinking about it, my brain goes for (a) and (d); that's what I would intuitively say.

About (b)-(c) and (e)-(f), are they optional, and therefore perfectly valid, or is there underlying syntax that makes them questionable or perhaps even unacceptable?  Modal verb "might" looks particularly out of place in (f), but I don't know if that's just my subjective view of things.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would say (a) and (d), also. The tenses do not agree in (b) and (e). I'd say that the modal verb seems superfluous in (c) and (f), since 'in case' already suggests 'might'.

Comment: The redundant forms c and f are sometimes used for emphasis, or just inadvertently. They're not wrong, just unnecessarily wordy.